# audio synthesis with MoMu STK

Tags: c++, ios, core-audio

Has anybody successfully implemented an Instrument using MoMu STK on iOS? I am bit stacked with initialization of a stream for Instrument.
I am using tutorial code and looks like something missing

```
RtAudio dac;

        // Figure out how many bytes in an StkFloat and setup the RtAudio stream.
        RtAudio::StreamParameters parameters;
        parameters.deviceId = dac.getDefaultOutputDevice();
        parameters.nChannels = 1;
        RtAudioFormat format = ( sizeof(StkFloat) == 8 ) ? RTAUDIO_FLOAT64 : RTAUDIO_FLOAT32;
        unsigned int bufferFrames = RT_BUFFER_SIZE;

        dac.openStream( & parameters, NULL, format, (unsigned int)Stk::sampleRate(), &bufferFrames, &tick, (void *)&data );
```

Error description says that output parameters for output device are invalid, but     when I skip to assign device id then it's not working as well.
Any idea would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RtAudio is only for desktop apps and there is no need to open stream when implementing on iOS.

example:

Header file:

```
#import "Simple.h"

// make struct to hold 

struct TickData {

    Simple *synth;    

};

// Make instance of the struct in @interface= 
TickData data;
```

Implementation file:

```
// init the synth:
data.synth = new Simple();
data.synth->keyOff();

// to trigger note on/off:
data.synth->noteOn(frequency, velocity);
data.synth->noteOff(velocity);

// audio callback method:
for (int i=0; i < FRAMESIZE; i++) {
    buffer[i] = data.synth -> tick();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I have a couple of apps in the store with STK classes running on them. Bear in mind that the setup required to run STK on iOS is different from the one required to run it on your desktop.

Here's a tutorial on how to use STK classes inside an iOS app:
https://arielelkin.github.io/articles/mandolin

Comment: This link seems to be out-of-date